# Same unix timestamp in two regions which are in the same timezone has different result

Tags: java, datetime, localdatetime

This code convert datetime to unix timestamp, but I have different result when I check the result in Mexico_City and Chicago, which are in the same timezone.

The result is :

Friday April 03, 2020 08:45:18 (am) in time zone America/Mexico City (CST) and

Friday April 03, 2020 09:45:18 (am) in time zone America/Chicago (CDT)

How to solve this problem?

https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1585925118&tz=America%2FMexico_City
https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1585925118&tz=America%2FChicago

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(2020-04-03 09:45:18, formatter);
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("CST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = zoneId.getRules.getOffset(LocalDateTime.now)
ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.of(String.valueOf(zoneOffset))).toEpochMilli //1585925118000
```

Comment: They aren't the same timezone, one is in Daylight Savings (CDT) and the other is not(CDS).

Comment: DST starts later in [Mexico City](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/mexico/mexico-city) than it does in [Chicago](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/chicago).

Comment: Hi, @ ThisIsNoZaku, what is CDS? They have the same time, so I thought they are the same timezone...

Comment: Hi @Matt Johnson-Pint, https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/difference/city/4887398/city/3530597, it shows DST is the same in those two places.

Comment: @zsf Comment by [ThisIsNoZaku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013198/same-unix-timestamp-in-two-regions-which-are-in-the-same-timezone-has-different#comment109679925_62013198) has a typo: `CDS` is supposed to be `CST`. --- `America/Mexico_City` and `America/Chicago` are **two different time zones**, and on April 3, 2020, [Mexico City](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/mexico/mexico-city) time is CST (Central Standard Time, DST starts April 5), while [Chicago](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/chicago) is CDT (Central Daylight Time, DST started March 8).

Comment: Further proof that daylight savings time is [dumb](https://www.sciencealert.com/daylight-savings-time-change-kills-people).

Comment: @andreas hi, what if I want to have CDT for Chicago? I used that in my current code, it doesn’t work since it’s not in the SHORT _IDS

Comment: @zsf - That site shows they have the same local time *now*.  It does not say they have the same local time on April 3rd 2020.

Comment: You should not use time zone abbreviations ("short IDs").  They are not unique. There is no way to know if "CST" is "Central Standard TIme", "Cuba Standard Time" or "China Standard Time".

Comment: @Matt got it thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not the same time zone

Your results say it:

> Friday April 03, 2020 08:45:18 (am) in time zone America/Mexico City
>   (CST) and
>
> Friday April 03, 2020 09:45:18 (am) in time zone America/Chicago (CDT)

Two time zones are mentioned, not one: America/Mexico City and America/Chicago. Both time zones have the same standard offset from UTC, -06:00, and both use summer time (Daylight Saving Time, DST), yet they are different time zones.

### Your results are correct

This year (2020) summer time began on March 8 in America/Chicago. So on your example date, April 3, summer time was observed. Summer time was *not* observed in America/Mexico_City on this day. There summer time did not begin until April 5. This difference explains why the time was 8:45 in Mexico and simultaneously was 9:45 in Chicago. Use the links at the bottom for verifying the dates of the summer time transitions in the two time zones.

### What is a time zone?

A time zone, as the name says, is a zone on Earth, but the concept also comprises the historic, present and known future offsets from UTC observed by the people in that zone.

Every time zone has a unique ID in the *region/city* format that is also used in the output from the Epoch Converter that you have used.

CST is not a time zone. CST is an ambiguous abbreviation. As mentioned in the comment it may refer to *Central Standard Time*, *Cuba Standard Time* or *China Standard Time*. You intended Central Standard Time, but even that is ambiguous: it may refer to North American Central Standard Time or Australian Central Standard Time. And while North American Central Standard Time is unique, unambiguous, it is not a time zone. It is the time used in America/Chicago and America/Winnipeg time zones (and more time zones) during the relatively few months of the year where standard time is observed. The rest of the year the mentioned time zones use Central Daylight Time instead. But yes, CST is also used in Mexico City for some of the year.

In Java `ZoneId.of("CST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)` gives you America/Chicago time zone because `SHORT_IDS` is defined to do that. This definition is there for one purpose only: to give you a behaviour that is compatible with what the now long outdated `TimeZone` class would have given you. Unless `CST` is used in your program for historic reasons and cannot (easily) be abandoned, you should neither use this nor `SHORT_IDS`. Use `ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")` if this is the time zone you want.

### Links

- [Time Change 2020 in Mexico](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/mexico)
- [Clock Changes in Chicago, Illinois, USA](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/chicago)
- [Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)
- [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)